# Change tableView textlabel when button is clicked swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

How to change tableView textLabel when different buttons is clicked. I have two action buttons brandButton and profileButton, what I want to happen is when I click brandButton brandInformation will show up to the tableView textLabel, and when I click profileButton profileInformation will show up.

```
import UIKit

class StreamDetailController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

 @IBOutlet weak var tableViewController: UITableView!

   var brandInformation = ["Hat:","Top:","Pants:","Shoes"]
    var profileInformation = ["tim", "master"]

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return brandInformation.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewController.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = brandInformation[indexPath.row]
        return cell

   @IBAction func brandButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    @IBAction func profileButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**

in this line:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewController: UITableView!
```

the variable is wrong and can be confusing. the `tableViewController` should be renamed to `tableView`

#### 1. Solution

add a class var to hold which view you like to see and chenge it with the buttons. then call `reloadData` on the table to refresh the content:

```
    cell.textLabel?.text = brandInformation[indexPath.row]
```

to

```
var isShowBrand = true

// [...]

    if isShowBrand {
        cell.textLabel?.text = brandInformation[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = profileInformation[indexPath.row]
    }
```

and also for the rowcount (you can also use the ternary operator:

```
    return isShowBrand ? brandInformation.count : profileInformation.count
```

(if you like to save it per cell then you need to save this info similar how you save the cell data `var showBrand = [true, false]` - but check that all 3 arrays have the same count of items to avoid `index out of bounds` errors)

#### 2. Solution

just make a additional array `tableData` and you set in the buttons the array you need to see. and all data populating is done with the `tableData` array (you need to change all `brandInformation` to `tableData`)

```
var tableData = [String]()

// [...]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewController.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
// [...]


@IBAction func brandButton(_ sender: Any){
    tableData = brandInformation
    tableViewController.reloadData()
}


@IBAction func profileButton(_ sender: Any){
    tableData = profileInformation
    tableViewController.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when I need to change all brandInformation to tableData? can you give me an example? thank you @muescha

Comment: `return brandInformation.count` to `return tableData.count` and also `cell.textLabel?.text = brandInformation[indexPath.row]` to `cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]` - because now all your data is only populated from `tableData` (you can name it as you like) and not from your arrays

Comment: oh, thats what you mean, I've done it already. the tableView is not showing. and when I click the buttons it still doesnt show up. I already put the reloadData. I'm still figuring out whats wrong here.

Comment: why does tableData.append(brandInformation) doesnt work?

Comment: why you do append instead of `tableData = brandInformation`

Comment: i add `reloadData` to tableViewController

Comment: just a note about this line ` @IBOutlet weak var tableViewController: UITableView!` the variable is wrong and can be confusing. the `tableViewController` should be renamed to `tableView`

Comment: I was just trying different stuff to make it work but the arrays doesnt still show up at the tableView.

Comment: empty array and empty table?

Comment: then you need to check why it is an empty array

Comment: please edit your question and add your full code of StreamDetailController below the question as new part.

Comment: Figured it out man! thanks alot muescha! didnt saw the tableView.reloadData() Thank you so much for your time